# input type search border-radius issue in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have an `<input type="search"/>` element (no other HTML).

Here's the CSS:

```
input[type=search] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

In Firefox 7 it looks great:

[image: Rounded corners on input element in Firefox 7]

However, in Chrome 15 the rounded corners are cut off:

[image]

[View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys9pw/)

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: FWIW, it works fine in Chrome 15 on Mac.

Comment: @BenjieGillam That's odd! I think I'm going to end up using a wrapper `<div>` and styling it instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to add `-webkit-appearance: none` to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `-webkit-appearance: textfield;`